Suddenly all resource Id in Google SDK sign in is gone
My application is integrated with Google login via SDK, and i have a test scenario based on Espresso/Compose to test it
previous all the resource Id is there, like below
    const val LIST_USER_SECTION = "com.google.android.gms:id/account_name"
    const val EMAIL_TEXTBOX = "identifierId"
    const val EMAIL_NEXT_BUTTON = "identifierNext"

but suddenly the page element can't be detected, and somehow via UIAutomatorviewer it detected become webview (android.webkit.WebView)
I can't detect the detail element via UIautomator neither via Compose now
And somehow when I try using Espresso Webview it is not working too with error
androidx.test.espresso.NoActivityResumedException: No activities in stage RESUMED. Did you forget to launch the activity. (test.getActivity() or similar)?
at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
I try to look any information related to this SDK change but got nothinh
Is there any idea or suggestion how can I make or maintain this end to end test scenario using Espresso or Compose?
Thank you


try to inspect using UIautomator but can't get any identifier
Can't inspect using webview (chrome://inspect/#devices), no page detected

I'm expecting a mechanism to inspect and make a test of Google login via SKD based on Compose Test

get information it might be related with the changes in 16 April
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#april_16_2024
